# WPF changing color of material at run time

Tags: wpf, binding, 3d

I tried several alternative to change the color of a 3D shape at run time.  The last one was attempted by creating a new class "MyMaterial" as follows:

```
public class MyMaterial : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Material amaterial;

    public MyMaterial() { }

    public MyMaterial(Material thematerial)
    {
        amaterial = thematerial;
    }

    public Material material
    {
        get { return amaterial; }
        set
        {
            amaterial = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TheMaterial");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Then using the following procedure to bind the 'material' property of an instance of the class above to the MaterailProperty of the GeometryModel3D of the shape as could be seen in the follwing procedure:

```
    private MyMaterial bindMaterialPropertyOfModel3dGroupToMaterial(GeometryModel3D model, MyMaterial myNewmaterial)
    {

        Binding myBinding = new Binding("TheMaterial");
        myBinding.Source = myNewmaterial;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(model, GeometryModel3D.MaterialProperty, myBinding);

        return myNewmaterial;
    }
```

Anytime I desire to change the color of the shape, I would create a new material with new color and set this new material to the aforementioned instance of MyMaterial, expecting to see this change reflected in the MaterialProperty of the shape, as, I believe, it should be due the the binding between the two, BUT THAT DID NOT HAPPEN

I am not so knowledgeable about binding.  I though that the target property needs to be dependency property which is waht the MaterialProperty of the GeometryModel3D of the shape is, correct ?

Can someone tell me what did I do wrong ? If this objective of changing the color at runtime could not be achieved through this type of binding, can someone give me an idea how if there is another way to do it ?

Comment: I do not see an implementation for `TheMaterial` property used in the binding. instead i see `material` property raising notifications for `TheMaterial`. see if that is expected.

Comment: pushpraj, can you point me to a FULL, SHORT example as I followed an online example which I supposedly used to bind the GeometryModel3D.MaterialProperty with "TheMaterial" property ? If not, if you can elborate on what you mean it would be helpful.